# SEO -- what's the deal with the enthusiasm for data scraping?

Tags: seo

So far, I can figure out only 2 major reasons for why SEO specialists would want to data-scrape a website:

1) Scrape competitors' websites to find-out keywords used in various Meta Tags, or other Tags, so that one can clone those keywords in one's own Tags.

2) Scrape Google Search results for top blogs (in our website's subject area), so as to spam their comment sections with inbound links to one's own website.

But in my mind, these 2 reasons do not justify the high enthusiasm for data scraping in our community.

What are the other reasons that I'm probably missing?

Comment: Steal your homework instead of doing their own, most common, scraping stock quantities so they don't need expensive, smart people working in their purchasing department.

Answer (score 2):

I won't go into every reason why they do but rather what they target. Scrappers may scrap everything while some will target certain criteria.

Business Data

- Telephone numbers
- Email addresses
- Address details

Link Spam

- Comment Spam

  - Moderation required
  - Do follow or no follow
  - Captcha required
  - TLD Type
  - Domain PR
- Forum Spam

  - Profiles with URL link enabled
  - Signatures links enabled
  - Captcha required
  - TLD Type
  - Domain PR
- Social Bookmarks Spam

  - Registration required
  - Captcha required
  - TLD Type
  - Domain PR

Content Harvest

- Data

  - Niche content
  - Social data
  - Keyword data
  - Whois data
- Backlink Data (not link spam)

  - Domain PR data
  - No follow / do follow data
  - Age of link data

Just from the information I've provided you should be able to establish hundreds of reasons why. Data = Money, it is estimated that Google makes over $250 each year from just one user who regular uses Google, so in otherwords, the answer is MONEY.